# Decode Data Received from Bluetooth device in Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, decode

I have configured Bluetooth Device that send data to Android App.
But I am receiving data in unreadable format.

Data I received from Bluetooth is below format.

```
���
��
���
```

Here is my android code

```
  private val mmInStream: InputStream?
        private val mmOutStream: OutputStream?

        init {
            var tmpIn: InputStream? = null
            var tmpOut: OutputStream? = null

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = mmSocket.inputStream
                tmpOut = mmSocket.outputStream
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e(TAG, ": " + e.message)
            }
            mmInStream = tmpIn
            mmOutStream = tmpOut
        }

        override fun run() {
            val buffer = ByteArray(1024) // buffer store for the stream
            var bytes = 0 // bytes returned from read()
            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                        bytes = mmInStream?.read(buffer) ?:0
                        val readMessage = String(buffer, 0, bytes)
                        Log.e("Arduino Message", readMessage.toString())
                        handler?.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, readMessage)?.sendToTarget()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    handler?.obtainMessage(CONNECTING_STATUS, 0, -1)?.sendToTarget()
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    break
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls convert the received bytes to hex string via bytesToHex extension method and log it

```
fun ByteArray.bytesToHexString(
    spaces: Boolean = false
): String {
    val format = if (spaces) "%02x " else "%02x"
    val sb = StringBuilder()
    for (i in 0 until size) {
        sb.append(format.format(this[i]))
    }
    return sb.toString()
}
```

Comment: hello now I am getting hex string but how can I get readable (actual data) from it?

Comment: Read device specifications. There muat be info about decrypting response